# Android Studio and JDK17

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've been trying to use this [API](https://github.com/tors42/chariot) in Android Studio via Gradle, but when I build my project it throws Unsupported class file major version 61.

From what I've researched it's because I use JDK version 17 and Gradle does not yet support it, but in the API it's stated that it requires Java 17. Is there any way I could still use this API in Android Studio?

Sorry if this is a newbie question but I'm fairly new to Android.

Comment: Some plugin probably can't handle JDK17 compiled classes yet. Wait a while and use an eralier JDK for now.

Comment: Unfortunately after I change Gradle's JDK to 16 and I set compileOptions to VERSION_16 I still get the same error. I use Gradle 7.2 and Gradle Plugin 7.0.3 which should be fine according to [compatibility](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html). Any idea how I can solve it?

Comment: Again: the problem is almost certainly not gradle itself, but some of the android-related plugins. If you get the **same** error message (including the class version number), then you probably just need to clean and re-build.

Comment: I tried cleaning + rebuilding on JDK16 but still the same error. Can I even use this dependency with JDK < 17? @5377037 What code should I provide? My build.gradle?

Comment: Yes try to minimal code according to stackoverflow guidelines or if possible share your debugging details.

Comment: I had the same issue today, OpenJDK 18 and Gradle 7.0.2. Upgrading Gradle to 7.2 just fixed the issue.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps you can try **Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1**. It's still in Beta at the time of writing but JDK 17 is bundled into it as the default according to the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/#jdk-17).

> Starting from Android Studio Flamingo Canary 3, the Studio IDE is bundled with JDK 17. If Android Studio is configured to use the embedded JDK, new projects will use the latest stable version of the Android Gradle plugin and JDK 17. However, existing projects might break, and you might have to manually set the JDK to a compatible version.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases), JDK 17 isn't supported yet in Android Studio. Actually, [JDK 11 was supported starting from version 4.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/past-releases/past-android-studio-releases/as-4-2-0-release-notes#4.2-bundled-jdk-11) which was released in April 2021.

Answer (score 2):

Android 14, Upside Down cake will contain Java 17 features. According to https://www.xda-developers.com/android-14/, these classes should be available to older devices as well.